# question about exponential distribution or exponential random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a post office that is run by two clerks. Suppose that when Mr. Anderson
enters the system he discovers that Mr. Smith is being served by clerk 1 and Mr. Brown
by clerk 2. Suppose also that Mr. Anderson is told that his service will begin as soon as
either Smith or Brown leaves. If clerk i serves at an exponential rate λi
, i = 1, 2, what is the
probability that, of the three customers, Mr. Anderson is the last one to leave the post office

and also

A barber has scheduled two appointments, one at 3 pm and the other at 3:30 pm.
The amount of time that appointments last are independent exponential random variables
with mean 50 minutes. Assuming that both customers are on time, find the expected amount
of time that the 3:30 appointment spends at the barber shop.

These are tricky quesitons, I 'm not sure how to do it.  I was told for the barber problem there's E(waiting time) and E(service time) but that doesn't seem like it's it, and the mean is 50 minutes, I cna't realy split that up into two, right?  how'd i solve the two?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning for the first one is that once a clerk is free and Anderson enters the window, the lack of memory of the exponential is as if the other's man service was just starting at this point.

Remember: the probability of a clerk finishing before the other one is $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$

P(Anderson last)  =  P (Anderson last | server 2 is first)P(server 2 first) + P(Anderson last | server 1 is first) P(server 1 is first) = $\left( \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 +\lambda_2}\right) \left( \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 +\lambda_2}\right) + \left( \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 +\lambda_2}\right) \left( \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 +\lambda_2}\right) = 2\left( \frac{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}{\lambda_1 +\lambda_2} \right)$